# instantiated object can not find method defined in a function in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, object, methods

I define a class Chalk in TypeScript, and some methods defined in the function, like this:

```
class Chalk{

   public init(): void {

     for (let color of ['black', 'blue', 'cyan', 'gray', 'green', 'magenta', 'red', 'white', 'yellow']) {
       
          this[color] = () => {consol.log(color)}
         }
     }
};

chalk = new Chalk();
```

but I can't access them from the instantiated object of Chalk when I try to execute:

```
chalk.red();
```

The editor tells me that chalk has no 'red' attribute, so what should I do to gain access?

Comment: Those methods _aren't_ part of the type. Also you never called the `init` method, so they aren't actually part of the value either.

Comment: In fact, I have called `chalk.init()`, I only left out it in my description above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach is to have `Colorful` interface and make `Chalk` implement it:

```
interface Colorful {
  colors: { [key: string]: () => void }
}

class Chalk implements Colorful {
  colors: { [key: string]: () => void }={};
  constructor() {
    for (let color of ['black', 'blue', 'cyan', 'gray', 'green', 'magenta', 'red', 'white', 'yellow']) {
      this.colors[color] = () => { console.log(color) }
    }
  }
};

let chalk = new Chalk();
chalk.colors.green();
```

Here is a [Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=22&pln=2&pc=1#code/LAKAlgdgLgpgTgMwIYGMYAIDCB7ANtxAV13QG9R10U8CBnALjPQG0BrGAT0dqjkgHMAuowAUASnQBeAHzoAbtjAATdAF9Q6kKBS4ktWlgAWSXK3RgAtgAdcMCzGgGc%20IiXIhK1FwyZtO3XgFhdHEpWQVlNUlSVQBuCipsCB44QhQoAlD3SkoEAhDbKESXdGwEFgByACNdFFYKgBp0atxCGEbmlA4kCA6K-jgkDj6BmAc%20iyR%20BygkPrgYJT6Ad0MwWD6OGFx8ZYrBCWycyig12gA6LzpmK7hBKRCJGSZqZLwYc-x%20EVuJTWP-moNPEtCBClRjKYHhAYMsjCZWOIQShIaxLjQ4BdRg4kaA8SAAPQE9DglEI6Gw%20GmXGgolUXT6KmsdygOk5KyEGpgFDmCDrcSMCIqFmE4nHdB5OAFGBFW6lcrMFqoepNFptPpdHojQbDVXY3qqybTaBzVULJaq1brdqqrY7bB7A5kBLi1li8XHU5gWg3DH3SSPMJkV60d6fbDfX6aNkeyjR905eNqEFukkyiHkgMwuGYVFIoA)

Comment: Thanks very much, the problem has been solved